# Имя типа объекта в javascript

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

Есть такой код:

```
var bla = {
  C : function () {return false}
};
var s = new bla.C()
```

Если выполнить такой код в консоле хрома и вычислить переменную s, то выведется значение:

```
bla.C {}
```

Вопрос:
Можно ли как-то после инициализации объекта bla, подменить формат вывода имени типа, т.е. вместо "bla.C {}" вывести  "УРА! {}"
Переопределение toString() у bla, s или у их прототипов не помогает.

Comment: именно в консоли ?

Comment: В отладчике в общем тоже, в хинтах, в expressions.

Comment: никак, можно конечно хром переписать... зачем оно вам надо ?

Comment: Откуда информация, что никак? Нам это нужно для удобства отладки.

Comment: а не проще в определении функции выводить отладочную информацию?

Comment: что это за удобство отладки путем смены имени прототипа объекта ? (вообще говоря тут наверное уже уместны слова Товльдса по поводу дебаггеров, я не в смысле что я его полностью поддерживаю, но все-таки меру в дебаге знать надо)

Comment: @eicto, да, фигня какая-то, если переопределен toString, просто вызывается console.log(s+''), и выводится строка которая нужно.